# How to prevent Firefox mobile app throttling AJAX requests?

Tags: javascript, ajax, firefox, mobile

I'm making a media player website that lets the user listen to audio in the background. After finishing playback, it makes a handful of AJAX requests to transmit data and switch to the next audio file.

The app works fine on desktop Firefox, but on mobile Firefox, I find that when the app is not active for a certain amount of time, these requests don't occur: my server has no log of receiving the request. I'm guessing this is a battery/bandwidth saving feature, but I haven't found any documentation on this.

However, in this case it makes the site unusable on mobile devices since I can't make those requests. Is there a way to work around this?